# Can't post to FB using Koala (Graph API)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm attempting to post to a Facebook group using the Koala Gem.

I am the administrator of the group.  I log in using Facebook Javascript SDK.

Before posting, I check permissions and have "publish_actions".

However, when posting I still get a 200 message ("message: (#200) Insufficient permission to post to target on behalf of the viewer [HTTP 403]):")

I've been struggling with this for a couple days.  Can anyone provide me with some insight?

Below is the code I'm using for permissions and to post.

```
graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(current_user.fb_token)
permissions = graph.get_connections('me','permissions')</code>
```

The array contains `{"permission"=>"publish_actions"}`

```
graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(current_user.fb_token)
message = "#{@group.name} - #{@message.message} - #{advertisement.message}"
graph.put_connection("#{fb_group_id}", "feed", message: message)
```

Comment: Any updates on this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should have updated awhile ago; forgot I left this.

The code was correct.  It's an API restriction.  Unfortunately it will work in a development (test) account, but won't work in a production account.